# Phonegap redirect to website and set cookies for it

Tags: ios, cordova, redirect

I have IOS app based on phonegap, I want to redirect it to responsive website and set cookies to still logged in with his credentials.

windows.location is not work

Thanks

Comment: you have to use inappbrowser plugin for that purpose .

Comment: I did, but it doesn't work with IOS, it works fine with android, and I don't know how to inject the cookies

Comment: Use localStorage instead of cookies.

Comment: And inappbrowser do supports IOS Platform .

Comment: I know that is support, but I don't know why it doesn't work on it, I figured out that there's a white list to allow my URL to be opened, but I can't find the white list of cordova

Comment: As @HassanALi said you need to install the inAppbrowser. Check why it doesn't a problem with iOs. I am sure that it is stupid issue. Then install the following plugin for the cookies:https://github.com/kristianhristov/cordova-cookie-master It is easy for work ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution

```
    function scripting() {
        ref.executeScript({
            code: 'document.cookie = "token=' + res.data.token + '";  window.location= "' + res.redirectUrl + '"; '
        }, function () {
            ref.removeEventListener('loadstart', scripting);
        });
    }
 var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(res.redirectUrl, '_blank', 'location=no,toolbar=no');
     ref.addEventListener('loadstart', scripting);
```

I hope it helps who had the same problem

Comment: hi above the code we are not suppose to use bcos we are using ionic v3 typescript and above code not taking , please share or advise, how do we achieve this code changes

Comment: Please note that adding listeners works only with "_blank" [target](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/#inappbrowseraddeventlistener). If you are openning the the "_system" browser, there is no other way than passing a token through a parameter (which is quite insecure, so please use https).

Answer (score 1):

use "window.location.href"

```
window.location.href = "your website url here"
```

it will solve the problem on iOS